# python parsing : String Comparison issue

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if( line == "Open Ended Schemes(Balanced)") :
        print "found"
```

My data text is Mutual fund information given by [this](http://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAV0.txt) link.

When I find the 'Open Ended Schemes', I wish to execute some code.
The problem is that `==` operator doesn't work here.
I tried some combinations with `line.rsplit()` but couldn't succeed.

I am a beginner with Python

Answer (score 3):

The readlines() method in python leaves the newline character at the end of each line.  Just change it to

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if( line == "Open Ended Schemes(Balanced)\n") :
        print "found"
```

Alternately, you could strip the newline from your line string before checking:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if( line[:-1] == "Open Ended Schemes(Balanced)") :
        print "found"
```

This should work as well.

Comment: The problem with `line[:-1]` is that it will always remove the last character, but the last line may not end with `"\n"`. It's safer to use `line.rstrip("\n")` instead.